# How to properly verify user without error in production

Tags: next.js, next-auth

In my NextJs app, after authentication I am trying to `verify` user using token, but continue to get an error in production. I have these files:

`// '/api/formSubmit'`

```
import 'dotenv/config';
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
import { withAccelerate } from '@prisma/extension-accelerate';
import { randomUUID } from 'crypto';
import SendNewEmail from './newUser';

const saltRounds = 12;

const prisma = new PrismaClient().$extends(withAccelerate());

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    try {
      const { brandName, firstName, lastName, email, password, provider } = req.body;

      if (!email || !password || !firstName || !lastName) {
        console.error("Validation error: email is missing");
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "An entry is missing" });
      }

      const lowercaseEmail = email.toLowerCase();

      // Check if User already exists (including unverified emails)
      const existingUser = await prisma.user.findFirst({
        where: {
          email: lowercaseEmail,
        },
        cacheStrategy: { swr: 60, ttl: 60 },
      });

      if (existingUser) {
        // User already exists, log them in
        console.log("ExistingUser from emailLogic:", existingUser)
        return res.status(200).json({ user: existingUser, message: "User already exists, please login." });
      }

      // User doesn't exist, create a new account
      const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds);
      const newUser = await prisma.user.create({
        data: {
          email: lowercaseEmail,
          password: hashedPassword,
          brandName,
          firstName,
          lastName,
          provider
        },
      });

      // Set the expiration date and time, e.g., 1 hour from now
      const expires = new Date();
      expires.setHours(expires.getHours() + 1);

      const token = await prisma.verificationToken.create({
        data: {
          token: `${randomUUID()}${randomUUID()}`.replace(/-/g, ''),
          userId: newUser.id,
          expires: expires,
        }
      });

      if (token) {
        await SendNewEmail({ firstName, email, token: token.token, userId: token.userId });
      }
      return res.status(201).json({ user: newUser, message: "User created successfully. Please check your email to proceed.", redirect: "/api/auth/signin" });

    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: `An error occurred during registration: ${error.message || error}` });
    } finally {
      await prisma.$disconnect();
    }
  }
  return res.status(405).end();
}
```

`//In 'email Template' - /api/newUserEmail`

```
import sgMail from "@sendgrid/mail";
import Email from "../emailfiles/new-user";
import { render } from "@react-email/render";

export default async function SendNewEmail({ firstName, token, email, userId }) {
    sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

    const emailHtml = render(
        <Email firstName={firstName} token={token} />
    );

    const msg = {
        to: email,
        from: "from-email.com",
        subject: " Welcome✨",
        html: emailHtml,
    };

    try {
       
        if (msg) {
            console.log("MSG FROM newUser:", msg, "token:", token, "email:", email); //successful
 await sgMail.send(msg);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error sending email:", error);
        if (error.response) {
            console.error("API response:", error.response.body);
        }
    }
}
```

`// 'Email component' - /api/new-user:`

```
import { Html } from "@react-email/html";
import { Body } from "@react-email/body";

export default function Email({ firstName, token }) {
  console.log("new-userJS", token);
  return (
    <Html>
      <Body>
        <p>Hello {firstName},</p>
        <p>Hope this email finds you well.</p>
        <p>Thanks for signing up. Please verify your account by clicking this link:</p>
        <p><a href={`http://localhost:3000/api/verify/${token}`}>Please verify your account</a></p> //Works in local environment
        {/* <p><a href={`https://production-site.com/api/verify/${token}`}>Please verify your account</a></p> */} //Throws error in production.

        <p>Sincerely,</p>
        <p>Team</p>
      </Body>
    </Html>
  );
}
```

and lastly in my `/api/verify/[token]:`

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    if (req.method === "GET") {
        const { token } = req.query;

        if (!token) {
            console.log('Invalid parameters. Token is missing. query:', query);
            console.log('Invalid parameters. Token is missing. Req.query:', req.query);
            console.log('Invalid parameters. Token:', token);
            throw new Error('Invalid parameters. Token is missing.');
        }

        try {
            const user = await prisma.user.findFirst({
                where: {
                    VerificationTokens: {
                        some: {
                            AND: [
                                {
                                    activatedAt: null,
                                },
                                {
                                    createdAt: {
                                        gt: new Date(Date.now() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000), // 24 hours ago
                                    },
                                },
                                {
                                    token,
                                },
                            ],
                        },
                    },
                },
            });

            if (!user) {
                console.error("There has been an error: Token is invalid or expired");
                throw new Error('Token is invalid or expired');
            }

            // Update user status to verified
            await prisma.user.update({
                where: {
                    id: user.id,
                },
                data: {
                    isVerified: true,
                },
            });

            await prisma.verificationToken.update({
                where: {
                    token,
                },
                data: {
                    activatedAt: new Date(),
                },
            });
            res.redirect('/api/auth/signin');
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            if (error.message === 'Token is invalid or expired') {
                return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Token is invalid or expired' });
            } else {
                return res.status(500).json({ error: `An error occurred during verification: ${error.message}` });
            }
        }
    }

    return res.status(404).json({ message: "Not Found" });
}
```

The issue is that the process works in my local environment:
User is able to: `Register > Get email > verify account > sign in to account`,

but in production I get this error:

`Error:`

```
Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"write after end","code":"ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END","stack":["Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end","    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)","    at ServerResponse.end (node:_http_outgoing:1017:15)","    at K.r.end (/var/task/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages-api.runtime.prod.js:20:13330)","    at /var/task/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages-api.runtime.prod.js:20:14144","    at K.r.send (/var/task/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages-api.runtime.prod.js:20:14153)","    at K.r.json (/var/task/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages-api.runtime.prod.js:20:14236)","    at handler (/var/task/frontend/.next/server/pages/api/verify/[token].js:1:1385)","    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)"]}
Unknown application error occurred
Runtime.Unknown
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?